# Printing excanvas

Tags: printing, internet-explorer, excanvas

I can't get IE to print my canvas (generated using excanvas)... I'm using the most recent version of excanvas.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/997831/canvas.html

(Note: I already tried having the canvas element already on the page instead of creating it with document.createElement)

Comment: found not working old 'fix' at http://www.asual.com/blog/?tq=charts

Comment: my specific problem is printing http://morrisonpitt.com/jsPlumb/html/jquery/chartDemo.html in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no good answer here. There has been a [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=33) open for well over a year regarding the printing of excanvas that has yet to be answered. You could try the [silverlight version](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/source/browse/#svn/trunk/silverlight) of excanvas it's a little better but still suffers from similar problems.

The only way to get it printed properly now would be doing a print screen and then printing the image. Unless an newer version of excanvas comes out or IE9 is released, native printing on IE just isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

my best shot currently is printing pre-rendered image

(see [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list) on google code)